Send Raw & Form-Data at the same time in postman
I'm using Postman now, I have a payload on my raw and on the form data I have files[], can I send them together? on my api im returning the files[] to return $request->file('files'); but i do get blank. does anyone know how to send them both at the same time?

I'd suggest putting any other data you need to send in separate multipart/form-data fields, alongside files

there's no other way around to send them both?

That is the way - it's a content-type which allows for multiple data types at once (as the name implies)

Does this answer your question? How to send multipart/form-data request using Postman
